# Deploying Flask application on heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my flask application on heroku. However it doesn't seem to work out. I don't know if it has to do with port or something else. The code however works on localhost. I'd like to know if I need to make some modifications in this code.

**Flask code :**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
import cv2
app = Flask(__name__)

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
def gen_frames():
    while True:
        success, frame = camera.read()
        if not success:
            break
        else:
            ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
            frame = buffer.tobytes()
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                   b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')


@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen_frames(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    """Video streaming home page."""
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000)
```

**html code :**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Live Streaming Demonstration</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8  offset-lg-2">
            <h3 class="mt-5">Live Streaming</h3>
            <img src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}" width="100%">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm new to both Flask and Heroku, and I'm stuck here. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand Heroku sets its own ports for each app so you could try somthing like this:

```
 app.run(debug=True, port=process.env.PORT)
```

If not please let me know